# Doctrine, field greater than value

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am current using Doctrine's createQuery (in Symfony).

For example, I have a query like this:

```
$dql = "SELECT * FROM table";
```

I am trying to add conditions to the above query. It seems that if you want to add a where condition, all you need to do is:

```
$query -> setParameter('new_field','new_value');
```

However there seem to be no solution to add a condition like this:

```
field > 5
```

Is there a build in solution to this? Or am I missing something? Workaround?

I am not using createQueryBuilder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parameters are only "variables" in your query, so for example here is what you can do :

```
$dql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE myField > :myField";
$dql->setParameter( "myField", $field );
```

Is that what you where looking for ?